# How to deploy WCF service on AWS

Tags: wcf, amazon-web-services

I have my WCF service on IIS which connects ios and android app.  Now I want to deploy this service on AWS how to do it?

Comment: just search in google how to do that.

Comment: I am not able to find it dude.Can you provide me a link.